# generating a new array within a loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops, variable-declaration

I'm doing a little programming experiment in C on ways to represent multiple lines of text.

I've come up with four ways: arrays of arrays, arrays of pointers, pointers of arrays, and pointers of pointers.

I've run into a little problem with pointers of arrays. Every time I create an array, it actually just reuses the array I already created.

Check out the output of the "pointers of arrays" (pa) part of my program to see what I mean:

```
variable    address         value
==========  ==============  =====
pa          0x10f500970

*(pa+0)     0x7fff6f0334bd

*(pa+0)[0]  0x7fff6f0334bd  t
*(pa+0)[1]  0x7fff6f0334be  e
*(pa+0)[2]  0x7fff6f0334bf  s
*(pa+0)[3]  0x7fff6f0334c0  t
*(pa+0)[4]  0x7fff6f0334c1
*(pa+0)[5]  0x7fff6f0334c2  0

*(pa+1)     0x7fff6f0334bd

*(pa+1)[0]  0x7fff6f0334bd  t
*(pa+1)[1]  0x7fff6f0334be  e
*(pa+1)[2]  0x7fff6f0334bf  s
*(pa+1)[3]  0x7fff6f0334c0  t
*(pa+1)[4]  0x7fff6f0334c1
*(pa+1)[5]  0x7fff6f0334c2  1
```

See how the address for each array are the same? Not very cool, is it?

**So here's my question:** Is there a way to actually declare a new array in a n > 1 loop, rather than rewrite the contents of the already existing array?

Here's the snipplet: (LIST_SIZE = 2 and TEXT_SIZE = 6)

```
void** pa = malloc(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(void*));

printh();

printf("pa\t\t%p\n\n", pa);

for(int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
{
  char txt[TEXT_SIZE + 1];

  sprintf(txt, "test %d", i);

  *(pa + i) = txt;

  printf("*(pa+%d)\t\t%p\n\n", i, *(pa + i));

  for(int j = 0; j < TEXT_SIZE; j++){
    printf("*(pa+%d)[%d]\t%p\t%c\n", i, j, &(((char*)*(pa+i))[j]), ((char*)*(pa+i))[j]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Thanks. If you have any other comments or suggestions, I'd be interested in hearing them, too.

The full source code is available at: https://gist.github.com/80m/7143558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `txt` is local to the `for` loop. At each iteration, the old `txt` variable becomes invalid, and a different `txt` instance is created. This means the pointer that was assigned `txt` in the previous iteration is not pointing to a valid object when the next iteration starts.

When the loop is finished, none of your pointers point to anything valid.

One way to fix this is to dynamically allocate memory for each pointer you want to assign to.

```
    pa[i] = malloc(TEXT_SIZE+1);
    snprintf(pa[i], TEXT_SIZE+1, "test %d", i);
```

You say you want "pointers to arrays", yet you declared of `void **pa`, which makes `pa` a pointer to a pointer. If you want `pa` to a pointer to an array, you would declare it this way:

```
char (*pa)[TEXT_SIZE+1] = malloc(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(*pa));
```

So now, `pa[0]` would be one 7 byte array, and `pa[1]` would be a second 7 byte array. You do away with the need to do any dynamic allocation within the loop.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't that turn "pointers of arrays" into "pointers of pointers"?

Comment: If a pointer variable is assigned the address of an object, it points to the object. It doesn't matter if the object is dynamically allocated or not. Dereferencing the pointer obtains the pointed to object.

Comment: Well, first of all the code you provided doesn't compile (pa + i needs to be dereferenced).

Secondly, where is the array that's being pointed to? You might be onto something but I'll have to experiment some more.

Comment: @80m: Sorry about that. My brain is not a high quality C compiler.

Comment: Your edit appears to be correct. I'm impressed. How did you come up with that? I thought it would be an array of char*.

Comment: Q: "[W]here is the array that's being pointed to?" A: In `pa[i] = malloc(...);`, `malloc()` returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, which is used to represent the desired object, which is in this case the array.

Comment: Q: "How did you come up with that?" A: If you mean the `char (*pa)[TEXT_SIZE+1]`, the parentheses makes `pa` a pointer to an array. Without the parentheses, it would have been an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the loops runs *pa* points to the same *txt*. So, the address that pointer *pa* is pointing to remains the same. If you want to point this to another location then try creating a different char[], say *txt1*, and assign it to *(pa+i)* during second iteration.

I tried this:

```
int i=0,j=0;

void** pa = malloc(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(void*));

printf("pa\t\t%p\n\n", pa);

for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
{

char txt[TEXT_SIZE + 1];
char txt1[TEXT_SIZE + 1];


  sprintf(txt1, "test %d", i);
  sprintf(txt, "test %d", i);
  if (i==0)
  {
    *(pa + i) = txt;
  }
  else
  {
    *(pa + i) = txt1;
  }

  printf("*(pa+%d)\t\t%p\n\n", i, *(pa + i));

  for(j = 0; j < TEXT_SIZE; j++){
    printf("*(pa+%d)[%d]\t%p\t%c\n", i, j, &(((char*)*(pa+i))[j]), ((char*)*(pa+i))[j]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

and got different addresses for different iterations.

I think the problem is not with the pointer but with the variable it is trying to refer to and it remains the same variable every time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes but what if I changed the LIST_SIZE to 3? The same problem would occur except this time with the txt1 variable.